# Flask/Bootstrap: Why is extends bootstrap/base nullifying my autocomplete?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am trying to use some basic autocomplete features with wtfforms but I cannot get autocomplete to work when I use a theme like bootstrap. The autocomplete works when we remove this line of code:

```
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}
```

How can I use these themes while also preserving autocomplete functionality?

```
# search.html

{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

<!-- This will break the autocomplete
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}
-->

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>


{% block content %}


{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}

<script>
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ url_for("autocomplete") }}'
            }).done(function (data){
                $('#city_autocomplete').autocomplete({
                    source: data,
                    minLength: 2
                });
            });
        });
</script>


{% endblock %}
```

```
# app.py

from flask import Flask, Response, render_template, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
import json
from wtforms import TextField
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'big secret'

cities = ["Bratislava",
          "Banská Bystrica",
          "Prešov",
          "Považská Bystrica",
          "Žilina",
          "Košice",
          "Ružomberok",
          "Zvolen",
          "Poprad"]


class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    autocomp = TextField('Insert City', id='city_autocomplete')


@app.route('/_autocomplete', methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete():
    return Response(json.dumps(cities), mimetype='application/json')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = SearchForm(request.form)
    return render_template("search.html", form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that you have to post your scripts before bootstraps, like so:

```
{% block scripts %}
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
{% endblock %}
```